# How to implement Django-Comment Reply?

Tags: django, django-comments

How to provide reply option to the user so that they can comment for an existing comment ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [django-threadedcomments](http://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments). Or if you want to save yourself a lot of hassle, look into [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) or [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/), which are hosted comment systems.